# How to edit and see changes without restarting Windows Azure Emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-compute-emulator

I can't find how to make changes, at least javascript and css changes, and see them reflected on the Azure Emulator witout restarting it.

Does anyone know if there is any option I have to modify?

This [blog post](http://blog.ntotten.com/2011/10/21/editing-a-local-windows-azure-project-with-the-emulator-running/) says "These changes were actually made in SDK 1.3 and refreshed in SDK 1.4.1"

I'm running SDK 1.6 and to see the changes reflected on the web site running on the Azure Emluator, I have to stop the application and run it again waitting for Windows Azure emulator to redeploy and start

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do that is to start the emulator without attaching the Visual Studio debugger.  If your Windows Azure project is set as your startup project, press Ctrl+F5 (or "Debug" -> "Start Without Debugging" from the top menu in Visual Studio).

With the emulator started, and no debugger attached, you can make javascript, css, html, etc. changes without needing to restart the emulator.

Comment: Sorry, is not working for me... besides that, if I start without debugging, I keep having this error message "Role instances are taking longer than expected to start". Anyway, I put a simple javascript alert, if I change the text in the alert and reload the page, nothing changes... of course I'm doing it by pressing ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, before SDK 1.3 you do have to redeploy your azure application on local emulator to refresh your changes, since at that moment web role was not hosted on IIS from your code location. But from SDK 1.3 you can change your front-end code (HTML, CSS, JS) without redeployment.

I guess you changed CSS and JS, could you please use Ctrl+F5 to refresh your browser, it will force reload all static files. Otherwise, your browser may cache them and you cannot see your modification.